# Unable to log in to npm when .npmrc present in project root

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, gem-fury, npm-login

I have a .npmrc  file in project root level and if I do 
`npm login` it throws an error

```
npm ERR! code UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY
npm ERR! errno UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY
```

After deleting `.npmrc` I am able to log in.
I have correct configuration for `.npmrc` as well

```
//npm-proxy.fury.io/myorg/:_authToken=mytoken
registry=https://npm-proxy.fury.io/myorg/
```

It tried to fetch from a private gemfury repository.

What I got to know is that the gemfury server cannot authenticate my machine from the token which I am having.

What could possibly go wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround was found in https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9580

Fix is to make `strict-ssl=false`